Why does removing the offset change the F-statistic of an anova model in R?
When a linear model with only a single categorical variables is defined without an offset, the F-statistic reported by summary() and anova() changes. This is due to the total sum of squares and degrees of freedom of the numerator being calculated differently. The values in the second row of the anova() output (the error terms) do not change. In the example below, I quote the first row of the anova table in the comment.
set.seed(13)
y <- rnorm(20, mean = 10)
x <- rep(letters[1:4], 5)

lm1 <- lm(y~x)
lm2 <- lm(y~x + 0)

anova(lm1) # x  df = 3  ss = 0.5346  ss/df = 0.1782  F = 0.1761  p = 0.911
anova(lm2) # x  df = 4  ss = 2073.24 ss/df = 518.31  F = 512.14  p < 2.2e-16 ***

It has been discussed elsewhere that removing the offset of a linear model is usually not a good idea, but that there are exceptions, and anova is one of them (see second answer by Joshua to this question). The question is also discussed here, but not with respect to the F-statistic.
I expected that removing the offset just changes the definition of the dummy variables, and the reason why I like to use a model without an offset is that I find it easier to to relate to coefficients that show the group means. Why then does R report a different F-statistic, which is also plainly wrong (the p-value is highly significant although the data are random)?
I can see that the problem seems to arise because the total sum of squares is calculated for lm2 as sum(y^2) rather than sum((y- mean(y))^2). This in a sense explains the extra degree of freedom attributed to lm2. The 'reference' or 'baseline' model that the F-statistic compares the model with the predictor x to has zero degrees of freedom, which would be appropriate if  y had been mean centred. But then the degrees of freedom, 4 rather than 3 in the example above, are still wrong. It seems therefore that removing the offset is always wrong also in the context of an anova model, if one wants to calculate the F-statistic. Is this indeed the case?
